# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}$$

What I have does is:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-e^0}{5x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{8}{8}\cdot\frac{e^{40x}-e^0}{5x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}8\cdot\frac{e^{40x}-e^0}{40x-0}=\\=8\cdot(e^{40x})'_{x=0}=8\cdot40e^{40\cdot 0}=320$$

Which is incorrect, where is the problem?

Comment: Since the limit of $/(40x-0)$ is taken, it should read $(e^x)’$ instead of $(e^{40x})’$.

Comment: @newhere Your fourth equality is false

Comment: $y:=40x$ then consider limit $8\dfrac{e^y-1}{y}$.limit $y \rightarrow 0$ $\dfrac{e^y-1}{y}=1$.And now?

Comment: why did you specify $x\to0^\color{red}-$?

Comment: L’Hôpital immediately gives $\frac{40}{5}=8$ as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$l=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}$$
Using the derivative definition:

$$l=\frac 1 5\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-e^{40*0}}{x-0}$$
$$l=\frac 1 5(e^{40x})_{x=0}'$$
$$l=\frac 1 5(40e^{40x})_{x=0}$$
Therefore:
$$l=\frac {40} 5=8$$

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{split}\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x} & = \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac{(1+\frac{40x}{1!}+\frac{(40x)^2}{2!}+\cdots)-1}{5x} \\ &=\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac{\frac{40x}{1!}+\frac{(40x)^2}{2!}+\cdots}{5x} \\ &=\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\biggl(\frac{8}{1!}+\frac{40^2x}{2!\cdot5}+\frac{40^3x^2}{3!\cdot5}+\cdots\biggr) \\&=8 \end{split}$

Comment: note that OP wrote $x\to0^{\color\red{-}}$, but it doesn't make much difference

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ohhh yes. anyway, the answer is the same. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is to consider that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{40x}$$ is the derivative of $e^{40x}$ on $x$. But the derivative of $e^{40x}$ on $x$ would be

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{x}.$$

In other words,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{40x}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}z=\left.e^z\right|_{z=0}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}\overset{\text{L'Hospital}}{=}\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{40e^{40x}}{5}=\frac{40\times1}{5}=8$$

Comment: +1; why the down vote?

Comment: Thankyou. Yes infact this is true

Comment: No reason for downvote. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short computation:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}=\frac15\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{x}=\frac15\Bigl(\mathrm e^{40x}\Bigr)'_{x=0}=\frac{40\,\mathrm e^0}5=8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Or back to basics. Let $f(x)=e^{40x}$. Then
$$
40=f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{x-0}=5 \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{40x}-1}{5x} = 8
$$